# How to remove .tex after running knit and texi2pdf

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have an R data frame that I run through knitr using the following code:

```
knit('reportTemplate.Rnw', 'file.tex')  # creates a .tex file from the .Rnw one
texi2pdf('file.tex')                    # creates a .pdf file from the .tex one
```

Inside my R script, I want to remove 'file.tex' from my computer folder afterwards. How do I achieve this? It is important that I do this within my .R file, since those lines are actually inside a loop that generates 1000 different reports from that template.

Comment: `file.remove('file.tex')` ?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, that does it, thanks (this is actually a bit embarrassing, since I'm aware of the `file` function family)! Would you care to submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: Thanks, but no. You should, though, feel **totally** free to answer the question and then accept your answer. Alternatively, if you don't want to do that, you can also just delete the question, since it's unlikely to be viewed many more times... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a family of functions in R that allow the user to interact with the computer's file system. Run `?files` to see functions that make it possible to, for instance, create, rename and remove files.

As noted by Josh O'Brien, in a comment to the OP, in this specific case, the command to be used is `file.remove('file.tex')`.